# $ARGV [1] Perl problems

Tags: perl

I am currently trying to set a debug flag using command-line arguments in Perl and I seem to be having problems with something which I thought was pretty easy.

```
    my $debugvalue;

    my $file = $ARGV[0] or die;

    if ($ARGV[1] == "debug")
    {
        $debugvalue = 1;
    }else
    {
        $debugvalue = 0;
    }
```

I am looking to enter a file followed by a word purely saying debug, if it doesn't then set the flag to 0.

```
test.pl file.txt debug
```

- Would set the flag to 1

  test.pl file.txt debug
- Would set the flag to 0

I would assume this how you do this, except whatever is inputted, it always drops into the first part of the if and sets the flag to 1.

Comment: This is a problem that [warnings](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) would have caught.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That would work fine, but you need to use the string comparison, `eq`, rather than numeric comparison, `==`.

```
if ($ARGV[1] eq "debug")
```

Also, you can shorten that up to just:

```
my $debugvalue = $ARGV[1] eq "debug";
```

In general, I prefer to use the environment for debug settings, though.

```
my $debugvalue = $ENV{DEBUG} || 0;
```

Then you can do things like:

```
DEBUG=1 test.pl file.txt
```

or set the test on for every run in bash or zsh:

```
export DEBUG=1
test.pl file.txt
test.pl file2.txt
test.pl file3.txt
```

or even have more than one debug level if you need aggressive debugging output to help diagnose a particular problem:

```
DEBUG=3 test.pl file.txt
```

and in your code:

```
warn "Fiddly Detail $x\n" if $debugvalue > 2;
```

Answer (score 4):

I almost always use Getopt or Getopt::Long.  Both in CPAN, super simple to use and very standardized.  For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Getopt::Long;

my $debug = 0;

my $result = GetOptions(
    debug => \$debug
);

my $file = shift;

if ( $debug ) {
    print( "debug is on for processing $file..." );
}
```

Of course, because it uses standard syntax, you would call it thusly:

```
#> test.pl file.txt --debug
```

or

```
#> test.pl --debug file.txt
```

**---- EDIT ----**

@zostay brings up a good point, debugging at various levels can be very useful.  That can be added in to the Getopot::Long approach thusly:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Getopt::Long;

my $debug = 0;

my $result = GetOptions(
    "debug+" => \$debug
);

my $file = shift;

if ( $debug > 2 ) {
    print( "debug is at least level 2 for processing $file..." );
}
```

And, for level 2 debugging, would be called:

#> test.pl --debug --debug file.txt

Answer (score 3):

You should do string comparisons with `eq` not `==`.

```
if ($ARGV[1] eq "debug")
```

Answer (score 1):

As folks have already pointed out that "eq" should be used for string comparisons and other ways of supporting a debug feature, the only other suggestions I'd add is that using perl's -w (warning) flag during development is also helpful for finding issues like yours:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
```

In your initial example, it would've returned a warning like:

> Argument "debug" isn't numeric in numeric eq (==) at ./foo.pl line 7.

It might also be cleaner to check for the existence of $ARGV[1] before using it in a comparison:

```
if ($ARGV[1] && $ARGV[1] eq "debug")
{
    $debugvalue = 1;
...
```

Comment: I would suggest `use warnings` rather than `-w`. For one thing, `-w` turns on warnings for code that you didn't write, which is rarely helpful. For another, `use warnings` isn't ephemeral like `-w` is (and there's no real reason to take it *out* of the code when you're done debugging).